# Универсальный IU под весь. Net

Tags: .net

Допустим, есть некий `ui` под какую - то определённую версию фреймворка, где можно выбрать пользовательскую `dll`, которая реализует определённый интерфейс и сделать некоторую работу.

Так вот, можно ли не ограничивать конечного пользователя, если будет решение остановить разработку?

Т. е под новые версии фреймворков, пересобираться ничего не будет.

На сколько я знаю, нельзя из младшего фреймворка, дёргать старший.
Думается, если `ui` будет собран под `4.5`, а пользователь подсунет `3.0+`, чуда не будет.
Есть-ли, варианты решения данной проблемы?

Comment: Если-бы, так было! То и собирать не нужно было-бы, а вообще, на худой конец, затолкнуть туда все версии и сделать тонну кода с проверками, если то, то-то-вон-то. Как у Ослика сделано... Но если тормознете, то никто не спасет. если, чудо пользователь не возьмет и не продолжит разработку. По этому в таких случаях, выкладывают сорци, чтобы товарисчи могли подправить под новые версии.

Comment: @And А там какой-то .Net Stadard же завезли. Неужели он не решает все проблемы? https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Comment: Насколько помню, там мало что есть, но стандарты тоже разные =) не забываем об этом.

Comment: Не знаю точно, возможно помогут плагины - в зависимости от доступной версии платформы грузить тот или иной dll. Либо использовать .net core 3.0 self contained сборку. В этом случае в exe будет уложен сам рантайм и все необходимое для запуска. И соответственно на компе юзера не важно что будет установлено. Но минус - .net core работает только на винде 10 +

Comment: @SultanovShamil, речь за полную поддержку не важно где запустить и под чем. А не только на win10. так можно сделать только если упаковать все старые и обновлять каждую новую версию и патчить снова. Больше никак, нет никакой единой сборки для любой платформы и NET кора.

Comment: обновления могут грузиться извне без проблем. На то и плагины и патчи. Нужно только чтобы сам хост запустился)) а поверх него UI разрулить уж разными dll под разные версии системы и платформы. Естественно что без обновлений никак. Это было бы конечно круто.